# Ошибка access valiation в lazarus

Tags: lazarus

Всем привет. Есть такая задача: на Lazarus составить две формы, первая работает хорошо, загружает данные  в мемо, сортирует, составляет хэш , но при открытии вторую форму ( при вызове в меню поиска) , она открывается, но при вводе данных и нажатии на кнопку выдает ошибку  access valiation. Помогите решите)

```
    procedure TForm1.MenuItem8Click(Sender: TObject);
var z ,key :string;
  i ,x: integer;
  f : text;
  a : array[1..15] of string;
begin
   key:=k;
   form2.ShowModal;
   x:=0;
   assignfile(f,'C:\Users\ermol\Desktop\учеба\2 семестр\Алгоритмы и структуры данных\лб3\laz\data2.txt');
   reset(f);

   for i:= 0 to 15 do begin
     readln(f,z);
     a[i]:=z;
   end;

   for i:= 0 to 15 do begin
    if a[i]=k  then x:=1
    else x:=0;
   end;

   if x=1 then ShowMessage('Строка найдена')
   else ShowMessage('Строка не найдена');

   closefile(f);


end;
```

Выше код из основной формы, ниже будет код второй формы которая открывается:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  k:=Edit1.Text;
  Edit1.Text:='';
  form2.close;
end;
```

Comment: Сложно сказать, Проблема, похоже, не в коде, который выложен. Можете выложить весь проект?

Comment: Кстати, вы объявляете массив `a` с индексом, начинающимся с 1, а в коде обращаетесь к нулевому элементу 'for i:= 0 to 15 do begin ... a[i]:=z;` Правда, это вызывает другое исключение `External: SIGSEGV`